# Aspose word - Table header repeat height issue

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I'm trying to repeat table header on each page. On first page, It looks fine but on rest of the pages, the height of the header is decreased and most of the data is hidden as below.

[image: PDF]

[image: Properties]

How can I fix the height of the header to look same on all pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using Aspose.Words. Please set the value of RowFormat.HeadingFormat property to *true* for header row.

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix it. Workaround is : Under Table Tools, on the Layout tab, in the Data group, click Repeat Header Rows. 
This messed up my table.
i un-did this change and it is working as expected. lol

[image]

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-a-table-heading-on-subsequent-pages-2ff677e0-3150-464a-a283-fa52794b4b41

[image]